# Fetch error - Missing \"data\" payload in the request body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, strapi

The GraphQL and Strapi API are changed and they added a parent level to the json object where the entire JSON object that has to be fetch must have a parent key called `data`, if you submit the request without this key, the API is rejected with a 400 error.

My JSON I submit is like this

```
{"title": "aaa", "rating": "3", "body": "aa", "categories": "5"}
```

The api requires it to be like this

```
{"data" : {"title": "aaa", "rating": "3", "body": "aa", "categories": "5"}}
```

How can I tweak my code in order to insert a parent key in this JSON object?

With Postman I am able to post the data in the Strapi, by submiting the data like this:

```
{ "data": {
    "title": "the best car",
    "rating": 7,
    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. ",
    "categories": [3,7,4]

    }
}
```

My full code is bellow:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client'
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const CATEGORIES = gql`
  query GetCategories {
    categories{
      data
      {
        id
        attributes{
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const token ="AlaBala"
const Create = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [body, setBody] = useState('');
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(3);
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState(5);
    const history = useNavigate();

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CATEGORIES)

    if (loading) return <p>Loading categories...</p>
    if (error) return <p>`Error! ${error}`</p>

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const review = { title, rating, body, categories };
        console.log(review)

        fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/reviews/', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization" : "Token " + token },
            body: JSON.stringify(review)

        })
    }
return (object etc...)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to change your fetch call to this, pay attention to the body field:

```
fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/reviews/', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization" : "Token " + token },
            body: JSON.stringify({data:review})

        })
```

Comment: you're a great man! @OddRadAche

Comment: I've been trying to figure out ways to solve this since I convert my form to an Object using FormData and I needed the data before. Thank you so much! Such a simple solution...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding making http POST requests to Strapi... Without having a "content-type: application/json" header set in Postman, I had the same issue.

But with that "content-type: application/json" header, it worked.

I checked via the VS Code Extension "HTTP Rest Client" (which is similar to Postman), and it's the same result.

So, just make sure the header is set with "content-type:  application/json" and you should be good to go.